# DataType Conversions in Db2

Tags: db2

I am currently stuck on concatenating three fields from a table into a single string. These three fields are of different datatypes.

```
Select 
    CASE COALESCE(CHAR_COLUMN,'XXX') WHEN 'XXX' 
        THEN 'CHAR_COLUMN is null' 
    else 'CHAR_COLUMN='''||CHAR_COLUMN||'''' END
    ||' and '||
    CASE COALESCE(DT_COLUMN,TIMESTAMP('1980-01-01-00.00.00')) 
        WHEN TIMESTAMP('1980-01-01-00.00.00') THEN 'DT_COLUMN is null' 
    else 'DT_COLUMN='''||DT_COLUMN||'''' END
    ||' and '||
    CASE COALESCE(NUM_COLUMN,111) WHEN 111 
        THEN 'NUM_COLUMN is null' 
    else 'NUM_COLUMN='''||NUM_COLUMN||'''' END
from 
S_DATATABLE
```

This works perfectly fine in `DB2/AIX64 9.1.7` but not in `DB2 z/OS 10.1.5`.
Error
when ran separately for numeric column

```
An unexpected token ",111" was found following ",111".  Expected tokens may include:  "CONCAT || / MICROSECONDS MICROSECOND SECONDS SECOND MINUTES".  SQLSTATE=42601
```

when ran separately for date column

```
SQL0171N  The data type, length or value of the argument for the parameter in position "2" of routine "||" is incorrect. Parameter name: "||".  SQLSTATE=42815
```

Please suggest what changes need to be done for this DB2 version. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure the statements were *exactly* the same on both systems?  The error message suggests a difference in syntax, such as a missing apostrophe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, regardless of the DB2 version concatenation requires character operands; you cannot concatenate a string and an integer -- DB2 will attempt to implicitly convert non-character data types to characters. It is best if you do explicit conversion to avoid errors.

Secondly, your SQL seems unnecessarily complex. Instead of

```
CASE COALESCE(NUM_COLUMN,111) 
     WHEN 111 
        THEN 'NUM_COLUMN is null' 
     else 'NUM_COLUMN='''||NUM_COLUMN||'''' 
END
```

you can simply do this:

```
CASE WHEN NUM_COLUMN IS NULL 
        THEN 'NUM_COLUMN is null' 
     ELSE 'NUM_COLUMN='||VARCHAR(NUM_COLUMN)
END
```

Note that in your original code you compare `NUM_COLUMN` with a character literal, which will also cause implicit conversion. Not all DB2 platforms support implicit conversion between all data types, so once again, do not rely on it but use explicit conversion instead.

Comment: I understand your point. Implicit conversion was working fine in one db2 version but not in other[i tried again to confirm]. Now as you suggested I have changed my code to have explicit conversion wherever required. it is working fine now. Thanks.